# Explicit assignment of addresses for C pointers

Tags: c, memory, pointers

```c
$ cat x.c 
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int *x,q;
    int *y,w;
    x=0x7fffffffe2bc;
    y=0x7fffffffe3bc;
    *x=3;*y=4;
    printf("%d",(*x)/(*y));
}
```

Produces a segmentation fault at runtime (<s>There are no compile time warnings/errors)</s>
**EDIT**: (Warnings:Thanks @KeithThompson)

> x.c: In function ‘main’:
>   x.c:6: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

```
[ 8626.812415] x[3198]: segfault at 7fffffffe2bc ip 000000000040054c sp 00007fff66a1dd70 error 6 in x[400000+1000]
```

But when I assign x, y to q, w as this

```c
$ cat x.c 
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int *x,q;
    int *y,w;
    x=&q;
    y=&w;
    *x=3;*y=4;
    printf("%d",(*x)/(*y));
}
```

and get the output I get `0`. I even checked the address of q and w from gdb, I got `0x7fffffffe2bc` for q

Why can't I force a pointer to point at a particular location and provide it with a value to be stored?

**EDIT**
The address 0x7fffffffe2bc is not *unallocated*.
This is the address of q from gdb

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at x.c:10
10      *x=3;*y=4;
(gdb) p q
$1 = 0
(gdb) p &q
$2 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe2bc
(gdb)
```

I understand this way of writing code is bad if not incorrect. I merely wrote this to see if explicit assignment of addresses works or not. I would never waste my time explicitly assigning addresses. Doing something like that actually sounds very retarded :)

```
$ gdb -q ./a.out 
Reading symbols from /home/eknath/needed2/a.out...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/eknath/needed2/a.out 
0

Program exited normally.
(gdb) q
```

Comment: Because of virtual address space? It would work only in 64bit version of DOS on a machine with 128Tb of RAM.

Comment: And what is so interesting in your 0x7fffffffe2bc address that you want to access directly?

Comment: @rodrigo, That is the address it spat out when I printed the address of q. I thought I could try explicitly assigning it

Comment: @ruslik, Major miscalculation

Comment: `int main(void)`, *not* `void main()`.  Whatever book told you to use `void main()` is a **bad book**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
int *x,q;
...
x=0x7fffffffe2bc;
```

is invalid.  It is a constraint violation, meaning that any conforming compiler is required to issue a diagnostic message.  You said "There are no warnings/errors while compiling this program", which means either that you're using an old compiler, or you're using a new compiler incorrectly.

`x` is of type `int*`; `0x7fffffffe2bc` is of some integer type.  There is no implicit conversion from an integer type to `int*` (except for the special case of `0`, a null pointer constant).

You *can* legally write something like:

```
x = (int*)0x7fffffffe2bc;
```

but it's a very bad idea.  It makes your program *extremely* non-portable.  It might (or might not) happen to work on your particular system.

Whatever it is you're trying to accomplish, this is not the way to do it.  You have no way of knowing that `0x7fffffffe2bc` (when converted to `int*`) is a valid address -- and even if it is a valid address, it won't be when you run the program in an even slightly different environment.

**EDIT**:

I tried reproducing your program on my system (where the addresses are quite different) by printing the addresses of `q` and `w` and then hard-wiring the addresses into the code.  The actual address change every time I execute the program, even when I don't change or recompile the program itself.  I think some systems do this intentionally, as a security feature.  (I see dmckee's answer already mentioned this.)

Printing the address of a variable, or viewing it with gdb, only tells you the address of that variable in that particular execution of the program.  Once the program finishes running, that information is *useless*, even if you re-run the same program with no changes.

If you want the address of `q`, the way to get it is `&q`.

Comment: I am sorry about the *no compile-time warnings*. Also, through gdb, the program executes fine. I am not writing this as a part of a software or anything. Just a test to get things clearer.. Thats All. The only part I truly appreciate in your answer is the part where you say You *can* legally write something like:
x = (int*)0x7fffffffe2bc; Thank you

Comment: @EknathIyer: Do you mean that you *did* get compile-time warnings?  And _"The only part I truly appreciate ..."_ -- then you're ignoring the very good advice you've been offered here.  What you're trying to do is fundamentally a bad idea.  It's a great shame if the only thing you've gotten out of this is a slightly cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Because you haven't allocated memory for the data, just the pointer. You are trashing memory at best and hitting an unallocated memory segment at worst. There is no way to know what addresses to use -- every time you run an application they could be different.

If you want to dynamically allocate variables (ie, under your own control), use malloc:

```
int *x = (int*) malloc( sizeof(int) );
*x = 2;

// when done, free the memory
free( (void*) x );
```

Comment: I would say "hitting an unallocated memory segment at best or trashing memory at worst", from my experience...

Comment: Yeah, I thought about flipping those. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is completely implementation/environment dependent (and is in general undefined behavior), but it does have its place in embedded systems and other environments where you don't have a OS layer between you and absolutely everything.

Many full services OSes randomize the starting address of the stack and/or heap in order to make some attacks harder, and if that is the case you won't be able to perform any reliable tricks.

Comment: So you are saying that if I switch off ASLR, my program should run properly?

Comment: No. It may run on your machine out of sheer luck, but won't necessarily run on someone else's. You need to allocate the memory for the data using malloc or a similar routine.

Comment: I'm saying that you can't make it work even on your own machine without turning off ASLR, and that your portability will be exceedingly limited even if you get it work. It was one thing to access the joystick port directly on a Apple ][+ or the IO pins on a ATMEGA168 (where these things are a documented part of the interface), it is quite another to try getting it to work reliably on a OS which puts a layer between you and *all* the hardware.

Comment: @dmckee: Furthermore, ASLR is a *feature*.  Turning it off is a bad idea.  That program *shouldn't* work; the way to make it work is to change the program so it doesn't attempt to use hardwired memory addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is neither in code nor compiler/linker. Both programs work as you would expect them to. Just there is one big **BUT**:
just because you **can point to** the memory it doesn't mean you will be **allowed to access it** by MMU (let's say Operating System).

Let me clarify this:
normally you can only access memory that you "own" (stack/heap). In both cases assignments to x and y are valid. The tricky part is when you access the memory (read or write). In the first case you assign some random value to pointer, therefore there is no considerable possibility that that location will be in program's scope (== can't touch this). Although, in the second case you are accessing memory location of a variable that you **might** own.

Why might? Because with optimization on variables q and w will be optimized out, because they are never used.

Remember: **never ever reference not initialized variable** unless you like problems

Comment: Please read the edit, that I added after you answered. This address is not out of scope for `./x`.

Comment: I think I was too quick to explain memory. If I understand your question correctly, you get 0 because of type conversion. Integer conversion always rounds DOWN, therefore int(3/4)=int(0.75)=0
Mangle with data types a bit.
And use second approach WITH initialised q and w

Answer (score 0):

```
void myFunction(char *addr)
{
#ifdef UMEM_DEBUG
    if (addr == (char *) 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef)
    {
        return;
    }
#endif
...
}
```

This works, and is a good example of when you do want to do this.  Just get the type cast correct based on the type of addr